# How to get records from multiple entities by text search in dynamics crm by javascript or api?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to retrieve records from multiple entities by matching text. Is it possible using fetchxml or web api? I want to use it by javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly achievable using FetchXML. Specifically you want to use the **like** operator. For example the following Fetch Query searches contact name and email for a given value:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="contact">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="contactid" />
    <filter type="and">
      <filter type="or">
        <condition attribute="fullname" operator="like" value="%[Insert Dynamic Value]%" />
        <condition attribute="emailaddress1" operator="like" value="%[Insert Dynamic Value]%" />
      </filter>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Write a similar fetch query for each table you wish to search.

**Is it possible to combine all entities together instead of requesting separately using fetchXml?**
No, by design FetchXML does not support querying multiple unrelated records. Although you can query against related records in a single fetch expression, you are not able to enforce OR conditions across multiple tables. For example, you cannot write a FetchXML query comparable to the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM contact
JOIN account on contact.accountid = account.accountid
WHERE contact.fullname like '%foo%'
OR account.name like '%foo%'
```

Comment: Is it possible combining all entities together instead of requesting separately using fetchXml?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be possible, though unsupported, to access Relevance Search via an API: https://bguidinger.com/blog/relevance-search-api